# Clipped and Scaled To Fill SwiftUI Image Blocks NavigationLink

Tags: swift, swiftui

When there is a NavigationLink in a container with an Image (that is resizable, scaled to fill, and clipped to a smaller frame), the NavigationLink cannot be pressed. I'm assuming that this has to do with the parts of the Image that have been "clipped off" still actually present and blocking the NavigationLink.

Here is a short example to replicate the behavior:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello, world!")) {
                        Text("Press me")
                    }
                }
                
                Image("background")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(height: 60)
                    .clipped()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

"background" can be any sort of picture from the assets folder.

I have tried to mess around with the zIndexes; that didn't work.

There was one hack that worked: I used a UIImage, cropping it to the aspect ratio of Image I wanted by converting it to a CGImage and back into a UIImage. After doing that, I could press on the NavigationLink again but it was obvious from my phone lagging that it was too expensive. I tried to work around this by saving the cropped image to the documents directory and then whenever the aspect ratio wasn't similar enough I would recrop, save, and reload the image, but this still took a toll on the performance of my project.

Please offer some advice on how I should handle this situation. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is alternate to zIndex (if other active elements are present in view as well) - disable user interaction with background image

```
Image("background")
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFill()
    .frame(height: 60)
    .clipped()
    .allowsHitTesting(false)     // << here !!
    //.zIndex(-1)            // << also force put below siblings
```

Comment: Is this bug or something hidden feature?

Comment: I don't think it is a bug, views are stacked in order of adding one above other... and visually visible does not equal hit-testable (interactive). Same might be in other scenarios as well, eg. after offset.

Answer (score 0):

Set `.zIndex(1.0)` to `VStack` of `NavigationLink`.

Tested : XCode 12.2, iOS 14.1

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello, world!")) {
                        Text("Press me")
                    }
                }
                .zIndex(1.0) //<--- here
                Image("ivana-cajina-_7LbC5J-jw4-unsplash")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(height: 60)
                    .clipped()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So it turns out for the specific situation in my project this does not work. I have multiple modular views with overlapping clipped images in a list, so it's much harder to set the zIndexes individually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative.

```
  public var body: some View {
        ZStack { 
                image
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                // > etc..
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
        }
        .clipped()
    }
```